# Dag task unsuccessful due to connection error with mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

My task is to create a dag performing three tasks...Task1 is to scrape data from 'https://www.lushusa.com/bath/bath-bombs/' website. task 2 is to store this data into sql database and task3 is to display that data
I have to see my logs successful in airflow UI
So far task1 is successful but task2 failed due to connection issue.
I got this error:

```
[2023-04-02, 10:25:33 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:100} ERROR - Failed to execute job 212 for task store_lush_data ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'; 20486)
[2023-04-02, 10:25:33 UTC] {local_task_job.py:212} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-04-02, 10:25:33 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2585} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I need you help to fix this issue..

Here is my code in python:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import requests

default_args = {
    'owner': 'sehrish',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='lush_data_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A pipeline to scrape and store data from LUSH USA website',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

def create_server_connection(hostname, username, password):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=hostname,
            user=username,
            passwd=password
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection successful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

    return connection

def scrape_lush_data():
    url = 'https://www.lushusa.com/bath/bath-bombs/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-tile js-product-tile'})
    data = []
    for product in products:
        name = product.find('span', {'class': 'product-tile__name js-product-tile-name'}).text.strip()
        price = product.find('span', {'class': 'product-tile__price'}).text.strip()
        data.append((name, price))
    return data


def store_lush_data():
    # connection = create_server_connection("localhost", "HHJ", "babyMuhammad1!")
    hostname = "localhost"
    username = "HHJ"
    password = "babyMuhammad1!"
    connection = create_server_connection(hostname, username, password)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('USE lush_db')
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lush_products (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, price VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);')
    data = scrape_lush_data()
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO lush_products (name, price) VALUES (%s, %s);', data)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

def display_lush_data():
    connection = create_server_connection("localhost", "HHJ", "babyMuhammad1!")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('USE lush_db')
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM lush_products;')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()


t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='scrape_lush_data',
    python_callable=scrape_lush_data,
    dag=dag,
)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='store_lush_data',
    python_callable=store_lush_data,
    dag=dag,
)

t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='display_lush_data',
    python_callable=display_lush_data,
    dag=dag,
)

t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: def create_server_connection(hostname, username, password):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=hostname,
            user=username,
            passwd=password
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection successful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

    return connection

Comment: Please raise and AirflowException from your create_server_connection() or wrap its invocation in a try except block for the error to appear in the logs. The connection isn't getting created in the first place and hence a cursor can the retrieved from it.